# jquery remove all items within div that does not have a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a asp.net Listview that is generating extra  elements, good thing is the elements that I do want have a class name. How do I remove the s without the specific class that i need in jquery thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `:not` selector:

```
$("div:not([class])").remove();
```

Edit: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xkc6D/).

Comment: The jquery docs recommend using .not instead of :not for efficiency, so the technically correct answer (the best kind of correct) would be $("div").not("[class]").remove();

Although, that probably wouldn't have as much of an effect on such a simple selector.

Edit: found a link that seems to prove me wrong... http://jsperf.com/jquery-css3-not-vs-not

Comment: what about if there is an inner table as well?

Comment: It will cascade; removing a div with a table in it will remove the table.

Answer (score 2):

class is just an attribute so you can select each one that doesn't have the attribute:

```
$('div:not([class])').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div:not([class])').remove();
```